# Solving a homogeneous underdetermined system of symbolic linear equations

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, symbolic-math

Let's say I have 2 symbolic equations in 3 variables:

```
syms u v w
eq1 = u+v+w == 0
eq2 =     w == 0
```

which both should equal 0. 
Is there a way to feed these equations to Matlab and have Matlab conclude:

```
u=-v
w=0
```

I tried the following:

```
%Attempt 1:
x=solve([eq1 eq2],[u v w]);
x.u, x.v, x.w 
%Outputs 0 for each of these

% Attempt 2:
[A,B]=equationsToMatrix([eq1 eq2],[u v w]);
linsolve(A,B)
%Outputs 0 for all variables and gives a warning "Warning: The system is rank-deficient. Solution is not unique."
```

So it only seems to return the trivial zero-solution. This is of course an elementary example. I want it to work for 81 intertwined variables.

Comment: So do you intend `eq1` and `eq2` to have values of zero, or are there arbitrary? I'm not sure how you could conclude `w = 0` otherwise.

Comment: Well yeah in my previous edit solve() contained eq1==0 and eq2==0. Edited the question for clarity.

Comment: It was mainly due to a mistake and I have solved the problem in a different way

Answer (score 1):

Since you have two equations you can only solve for two variables, not for three. You want to see `u=-v` and `w=0`, that is a solution in `u` and `w` but not in `v`.

For me `x = solve([eq1,eq],u,w)` works, it gives `x.u=-v` and `x.w=0`.

Comment: Hm that seems plausible, I might have made a mistake when trying to solve a much bigger real example...